# VSCode not rendering Markdown with latex in Jupyter notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, latex, markdown

The following Markdown code from a Jupyter notebook produces an error in VSCode. Some initial googling suggests this has to do with Latex rendering in markdown in vscode? Any suggetions on how to fix it, whether it's a VSCode setting, a VSCode extension, or something else? For what it's worth, the equation renders just fine in a browser (i.e., outside of VSCode).

[image: Error in VSCode]

```
<a name="3.5"></a>
### 3.5 Gradient for regularized logistic regression

In this section, you will implement the gradient for regularized logistic regression.


The gradient of the regularized cost function has two components. The first, $\frac{\partial J(\mathbf{w},b)}{\partial b}$ is a scalar, the other is a vector with the same shape as the parameters $\mathbf{w}$, where the $j^\mathrm{th}$ element is defined as follows:

$$\frac{\partial J(\mathbf{w},b)}{\partial b} = \frac{1}{m}  \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} (f_{\mathbf{w},b}(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})  $$

$$\frac{\partial J(\mathbf{w},b)}{\partial w_j} = \left( \frac{1}{m}  \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} (f_{\mathbf{w},b}(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}) - y^{(i)}) x_j^{(i)} \right) + \frac{\lambda}{m} w_j  \quad\, \mbox{for $j=0...(n-1)$}$$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce your error...`\mbox{}` seems to be problematic.
Under the assumption, that you are using `\mbox` for the correct spacing, there is a simple alternative to fix it. `\,` creates a half space width...
The following code should do the trick:

```
In this section, you will implement the gradient for regularized logistic regression.


The gradient of the regularized cost function has two components. The first, $\frac{\partial J(\mathbf{w},b)}{\partial b}$ is a scalar, the other is a vector with the same shape as the parameters $\mathbf{w}$, where the $j^\mathrm{th}$ element is defined as follows:

$$\frac{\partial J(\mathbf{w},b)}{\partial b} = \frac{1}{m}  \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} (f_{\mathbf{w},b}(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})  $$  

$$\frac{\partial J(\mathbf{w},b)}{\partial w_j} = \left( \frac{1}{m}  \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} (f_{\mathbf{w},b}(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}) - y^{(i)}) x_j^{(i)} \right) + \frac{\lambda}{m} w_j  \quad\, for\,\,j=0...(n-1)$$
```

```
for\,\,j=0...(n-1)
```

With the result...
[image]

Hope this fix helps. I am still looking for an explaination though

Comment: One explanation I found was that VsCode uses KaTeX to parse LaTeX. In LaTeX there a command called \mbox. \mbox command is not supported in KaTeX so the error happens. 

Ideally, I wouldn't have to change the notebook to get it to load properly in VSCode

Comment: I came to the same conclusion after digging around. Unfortenatly `\mbox` will [not be supported by katex in the next time](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135261)

Comment: How do we get them to add support?

Comment: You could open a issue on github and try  to get enough community support to move the issue to the backlog ... https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Issues-Triaging#our-triaging-flow